# Receiving the message: Cannot GET / error while using NodeJS and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I know similar questions have been answered multiple times over the years and I have scoured through just about all of them and can't seem to figure out what my issue is.

I am getting the Cannot GET / error with NodeJS when opening the localhost:5000 in browser. When inspecting I can see it says "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)", which I think may be related to my controllers file.

Note: I am trying to code based off of this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngc9gnGgUdA

The "This works" message previously showed up for me and the array symbol still shows up. It is the JSX structure part where I first run into this issue (begins at 28:50). I feel I have done exactly as the tutorial explains, but perhaps I need a better person than me to look at it.

**server/Index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
// import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import cors from 'cors';

import postRoutes from './routes/posts.js';

const app = express();

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);

app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL = 'mongodb+srv://*****:******@cluster0.kwo9h.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
    .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port: ${PORT}`)))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

    mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

**controllers/posts**

```
import PostMessage from '../models/postMessage.js';
// import router from '../routes/posts.js';


export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const postMessages = await PostMessage.find();

        // console.log(postMessages);

        res.status(200).json(postMessages);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
    }
}

export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    const
```

post = req.body;

```
const newPost = new PostMessage(post);

try {
    await newPost.save();

    res.status(201).json(newPost);
} catch (error) {
    res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
}
```

}

**routes/posts**

```
import express from 'express';

import { getPosts, createPost } from '../controllers/posts.js'

const router = express.Router();

// localhost:5000/posts

router.get('/', getPosts);
router.post('/', createPost);

export default router;
```

Any help would definitely make my day. Thank you!

Comment: Please share your `index.js` file.

Comment: I have added my index.js file. Thanks for reviewing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tutorial, there are actually **2 applications**. The first one is the backend (NodeJS), which is running on port 5000. The second one is the frontend (React), which is running on port 3000.

At 30:50, you see that the mentor typing "npm run start" on the 2nd terminal to start the react application.

At 33:12, the URL is **localhost:3000**, which is pointing to React application. It isn't localhost:5000. You get the error 404 because in the NodeJS part, there is no GET "/" route. So you just need to use the correct URL.

Comment: Good observation. However, there wasn't anything in the video that showed him setup the port 3000, so I did not do that. I'm now wondering why his front end is on port 3000 and how I would/if I should try and run both ports.

Comment: Looking into your tip I was able to figure it out. For one, I should have kept both the client side and server side terminals running individually. Previously I only had the server side running. Keeping them in the dual windows helps. I also had installed material-ui/core only on the server side and so I corrected this and installed on the client side. And for the last step, all I had to do was compile rge client side and the build deployed successfully. THANK YOU TO EVERYONE WHO RESPONDED AND I LOVE THIS COMMUNITY!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use router.
declare the express app first and attach the router to it.

```
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', getPosts);
router.post('/', createPost);

app.use('/', router)
export default router;
```

Comment: Hmmm it seems I am getting the same result as before, even after making these changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have no route declared for http://localhost:5000 - your router is under /posts

So you need to visit http://localhost:5000/posts to see something.

If you want something to appear directly at http://localhost:5000 you can do something like

**index.js**

```
const app = express();

app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('works')
})

app.use('/posts', postRoutes);
```

What do you want to see at http://localhost:5000?

1. If you want to display a index.html website you can put your index.html file in a a folder e.g. public and add

app.use(express.static('public'))

2. If you want your posts to appear at http://localhost:5000 then change your routing

**index.js**

```
const app = express();
app.use('/', postRoutes)
```

Comment: While what you recommended did work, it was note quite what I was looking for. I do appreciate you taking the time to help me with my issue!